# How Do I Use Tkinter Commands When Saving Widgets to a List?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, frame

I'm working on a program where I need to create widgets in a for loop, but each widget needs to be independent. My research has taught me I need to save the widgets to a list.

In the test I'm trying below I just want the frame to print it's ID when clicked. Currently when a frame is clicked nothing happens.

```
def month(self):
    self.monthFrame = []

    for i in range(12):
        self.monthFrame.append(tk.Frame(tkRoot, width=150, height=300))
        self.monthFrame[i].config(bd=2, relief='groove', background='GREEN')
        self.monthFrame[i].grid(row=1, column=i, sticky=tk.W)
        self.getFrame(idx=i)

def getFrame(self, idx):
    self.monthFrame[idx].bind('<Button-1>', self.printFrame(idx))

def printFrame(self, idx):
    self.monthFrame[idx].config(bd=2, relief='groove', background='RED')
```

Comment: Assigning to an attribute named `command` does absolutely nothing to any Tkinter widget.  (Perhaps you're thinking of how a Button is used, but that use of `command` is an option passed to the initial widget creation or to `.config()`, NOT an attribute of the widget.).  You're doing the right thing in `getFrame()`, you just need to actually call that method (inside the `for` loop, probably) so that the binding gets done.

Comment: I changed the code a bit and it uses getFrame now, but all 12 frames are printed and without even clicking on anything.

Comment: You need to bind to a function that will call `print()`, rather than calling `print()` immediately.

Comment: Ok, It seems I got it to work. Getting the actual frame ID will have to be based on the actual x and y values since the print shows "Frame<ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=1 x=112 y=144>".

Comment: I'm trying another test where each frame on click on should change color, except all the frames change color at the same time.

Comment: `self.monthFrame[idx].bind('<Button-1>', self.printFrame(idx))` should be `self.monthFrame[idx].bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.printFrame(idx))`.